# Retrieve json data through route in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel 5.3 for my API and my frontend is not included in my view of Laravel. My frontend is on 80 port whereas my API is on 8080 port so whenever I want to make a communication in between I will call Laravel API.

I don't know how to retrive the requested JSON data in Laravel using post route and I want to return the same data in response just to check whether it is working fine or not.

**so here is my route and controller(please guide me if i went wrong in my code):**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api','cors'],'prefix' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::get('inquiry', 'inquiryController@store');      
});
```

**and controller is:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class inquiryController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data=$requst->json->all();
        return response()->json([$data]);
    }
}
```

But this code is not working properly. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Try to do like this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $data = $request->all();
  return response()->json($data);  
}
```

Comment: i am sending a post request and i got a error "internal server error "

Comment: Try this way return response()->json($data, 200, []);

Comment: VerifyCsrfToken.php
  First allow your api
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    if (!$request->is('api/*'))
    {
      return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }
    
    return $next($request);
    
    //return parent::handle($request, $next);
  }